# "Mi piacerebbe che" + "ci fosse" oppure "ci sia"?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

Ho imparato che si dice:

> C'è il sole.

Ma ho trovato la seguente  espressione:

> Mi piacerebbe che domani CI FOSSE il sole.

Direi però

> Mi piacerebbe che domani ci sia il sole.

Perché si usa "ci fosse" e non "ci sia"?

Comment: Quando hai scritto "ci+ fare", vuoi dire "ci fosse"? Perché "fosse" è il verbo "essere", non il verbo "fare".

Comment: La differenza sta nel condizionale della frase principale: “vorrei che tu domani andassi a fare la spesa”, “voglio che tu domani vada a fare la spesa”.

Comment: Non ho tempo per scrivere una risposta, ma per chi può, è utile Serianni XIV.58(e). Il succo è che vanno bene entrambe le costruzioni, ma si usa più spesso l'imperfetto.

Comment: @DaG In "Prima lezione di grammatica", Serianni afferma chiaramente (p. 63) che il congiuntivo imperfetto è d'obbligo con verbi della principale che indicano un desiderio (quindi anche mi piacerebbe"), mentre il congiuntivo presente si usa con verbi di altre aree semantiche: "direi che a quest'ora si possa anche incominciare". "Incominciare" da parte di Serianni mi ha un po' stupito, tra l'altro, visto che si tratta di una variante dell'italiano popolare di "cominciare".http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incominciare/

Comment: @DaG: Sicuramente è come hai detto, ma Serianni XIV.58(e) fa riferimento a subordinate oggettive e qui si tratta di una subordinata soggettiva.

Comment: @DaG: Tuttavia, in XIV.66 si legge in riferimento alle subordinate soggettive: «Per quanto riguarda uso dei tempi, uso del condizionale, omissione del che, [...] la sintassi delle soggettive corrisponde puntualmente a
quella, già descritta, delle oggettive». Immagino che questo significhi che quello spiegato in XIV.58(e) sia anche valido in questo caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrivo una risposta basata sul contenuto del libro *Italiano* di Luca Serianni.

Innanzitutto, notiamo che nella frase

> Mi piacerebbe che domani [...]

abbiamo a che fare con una subordinata soggettiva (ad esempio, "il sole" è il soggetto della frase "mi piace il sole").

Nelle sezioni XIV.57-58, Serianni spiega come si concordano i tempi verbali delle proposizioni reggente e subordinata nel caso di subordinate oggettive (cioè, proposizioni che hanno la funzione di complemento oggetto). Comunque, la sezione XIV.66 riporta in riferimento alle subordinate soggettive (quelle che fanno la funzione di soggetto):

> Per quanto riguarda uso dei tempi, uso del condizionale, omissione del che, [...] la sintassi delle soggettive corrisponde puntualmente a quella, già descritta, delle oggettive.

Cioè, quello spiegato per la concordanza dei tempi nelle sezioni XIV.57-58 è anche valido per le subordinate soggettive.

La sezione XIV.57 riguarda la concordanza dei tempi quando la subordinata è al congiuntivo. Spiega, tra l'altro, che, quando la proposizione reggente è al condizionale presente, di solito la subordinata va al congiuntivo presente. Questo è l'esempio che appare sul libro:

> immaginerei che egli faccia bene.

Tuttavia, nella sezione XIV.58.e) si può leggere:

> Se nella reggente figura il condizionale presente di un verbo indicante volontà, desiderio, opportunità (come *volere*, *desiderare*, *pretendere*, *esser conveniente* e simili; un'ampia lista in MORETTI-ORVIETO 1979: I 148), la dipendente si costruisce col congiuntivo imperfetto più spesso che col congiuntivo presente. Esempi: «E che vorrebbe ch'io facessi?» (Manzoni, *I Promessi Sposi*, II 20); «Io, figlia, non pretenderei che mia madre salisse per me novanta, cento scalini» (Pirandello, *Così è* [*se vi pare*], V 28).

Questo è ciò che accade con il verbo "piacere" che appare nella frase della domanda, verbo che esprime desiderio. Cioè, la subordinata di solito si costruisce congiuntivo imperfetto "fosse"

> Mi piacerebbe che domani ci fosse il sole

anche se la spiegazione precedente non sembra escludere che si possa anche fare col congiuntivo presente "sia" (si afferma però che è molto meno usato).

Nel libro [*L'ora d'italiano*](https://books.google.es/books?hl=it&id=KmhaDwAAQBAJ&q=desiderio#v=snippet&q=desiderio&f=false) lo stesso Serianni dà un'interessante spiegazione su perché si usa il congiuntivo imperfetto nella subordinata quando il verbo della regente è un verbo al condizionale presente che esprime desiderio o un'aspirazione:

> Vediamone una: perché si dice «vorrei che tu studiassi», con apparente violazione della
>   correlazione dei tempi (*vorrei* è un presente e ci si aspetterebbe nella completiva il congiuntivo presente, come in «voglio che studi»). Perché il condizionale di *volere* e di altri verbi indicanti un desiderio o un'aspirazione richiede la reggenza tipica dei verbi al passato: se usa il condizionale, il
>   parlante mostra di credere poco alla realizzabilità del proprio desiderio, lo dà
>   quasi come se fosse già alle spalle (quindi: «*vorrei* che tu studiassi», ma non m'illudo che tu lo faccia; «*voglio* che tu studi», e sono convinto che la mia autorità ti costringerà a farlo).

Anche sul [sito web di domande e risposte della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_1669.html), si trova questa domanda:

> Da qualche parte ho letto e trovato scritto queste frasi: "mi piacerebbe che dicesse queste cose di me"; "basterebbe che prendesse la bottiglia per versarsi l'acqua". Il verbo *piacere* e *bastare* che sono al condizionale dovrebbero reggere dunque il congiuntivo presente perché non esprimono né desiderio, né una volontà, né una necessità, dunque per correttezza dovrebbero essere così gli enunciati: "mi piacerebbe che dica queste cose di me"; “basterebbe che prenda la bottiglia…". No?

Come risposta alla prima parte di questa domanda, cioè, quella che ha a che vedere con la frase con il verbo "piacere", si legge:

> Scindiamo le due frasi. Nella prima, perché mai il verbo *piacere* non dovrebbe esprimere desiderio? Lo esprime eccome, quindi *mi piacerebbe che dicesse*.

Comment: Vorrei ringraziare @DaG, che è quello che ha indicato questa risposta.

Comment: Che è esattamente quello che ho già scritto io sopra: " In "Prima lezione di grammatica", Serianni afferma chiaramente (p. 63) che il congiuntivo imperfetto è d'obbligo con verbi della principale che indicano un desiderio (quindi anche mi piacerebbe"), mentre il congiuntivo presente si usa con verbi di altre aree semantiche: "direi che a quest'ora si possa anche incominciare".

Comment: Perfetto . Grazie.